# Why does turning bold off not work when adding new text from C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I want to add text from C# to a Winword document and turn bold on an off.

Using this, **abc** is displayed bold. Bold then is programmatically turned  off, so the following text appears unbold when typed in Winword directly.

```
{
    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Font.Bold = 1;
    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Text = "abc";
    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove);

    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Font.Bold = 0;
    // continue typing text in Winword now, the text isn't bold
}
```

Here I get bold **abcxyz**, although bold has been turned off.

```
{
    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Font.Bold = 1;
    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Text = "abc";

    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.EndKey(Word.WdUnits.wdStory, Word.WdMovementType.wdMove);

    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Font.Bold = 0;

    // this text is bold, although bold  had been turned off
    objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Text = "xyz"; 
}
```

Why is "xyz" bold when added programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround like this now:

```
{
    object start = 0;
    object end = 0;

    Word.Range rng = objWinWordControl.document.Range(ref start, ref end);
    rng.Text = "abc";
    rng.Font.Bold = 1;

    start = rng.Text.Length;
    end = rng.Text.Length;

    rng = objWinWordControl.document.Range(ref start, ref end);
    rng.Text = "xyz";
    rng.Font.Bold = 0;
}
```

but compared to:

```
 objWinWordControl.document.Application.Selection.Text = "abc";
```

it has a very poor performance.